# 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted when sending mail

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, gmail

Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z7sm6546905pgb.24 - gsmt

This error occurs when I try to send email

```
    QUEUE_DRIVER=database
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAM=taibarani780@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Have you set Mail_password to anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=taibarani780@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=""
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Make sure that your password is rounded by the double quotes "".

Comment: i have tried this but i still get the error with corrrect credentials, why is this and can i fix it?

Comment: You saved me a day

Answer (score 0):

Solution post May 2022:

If you are seeing this issue after May 2022, The issue you are having is related to googles remove [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) setting from our google accounts.  Less secure apps was what enabled us to use our google login and passwords with their smtp server.

In order to use it now you must enable 2fa on your google account and configure an apps password.  You can then use the apps password in place of your actual google password to connect to the smtp server.

[Quick fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)