# Trigger Email Firebase Extension - Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: firebase, gmail

I'm trying to setup and explore this firebase extension Trigger Email, as per other tutorial, you can use your personal gmail account (this might be where my problem starts) rather than using mail providers such as SendGrid / Postmark.

When I tried using it, I get the following logs on my document

[image]

I've followed workarounds here and in other sites however the problem persist.
Despite applying the following solutions I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57196305/invalid-login-535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-accepted), [here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953488/535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-accepted-when-sending-mail) and also [here](https://www.folkstalk.com/2022/09/535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-accepted-learn-more-atn5-7-8-https-support-google-com-mail-pbadcredentials-q17-20020a17090676d100b006fea59ef3a5sm9650868ejn-32-gsmtp-with-code-examples.html)
[image]

[image]

Does anyone have like another workaround or documentation to follow on setting up? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are having is related to googles remove [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) setting from our google accounts.  Less secure apps was what enabled us to use our google login and passwords with their smtp server.

In order to use it now you must enable 2fa on your google account and configure an apps password.  You can then use the apps password in place of your actual google password to connect to the smtp server.

[Quick fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)

Answer (score 1):

**Working Solution in My Case**

Apparently despite being Optional on the Extension Documentation, after you've enabled 2FA and App Password (selecting others on the device works for me). You have to configure the SMTP Password field as well to match the App Password you've just generated. It now works properly.